# How to format an array of floats into a string

Tags: python, format

I have a very simple question. I have an array of floats

```
   a = array([0.01,0.1,10,100,1000])
```

I would like to print this array so that the end result looks something like

```
   10$^-2$, 10$^-1$, ....
```

Is that possible with the `%` command?

Comment: You should probably specify the behavior of the program for `1`, as well as for floats which are not powers of 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as a one-liner:

```
["10$^{}$".format(int(math.log10(num))) for num in a]
```

or more clearly:

```
from math import *

def toLatex(powerOf10):
    exponent = int( log10(powerOf10) )
    return "10$^{}$".format(exponent)

nums = [10**-20, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10**20]
[(x, toLatex(x)) for x in nums]
```

```
[(1e-20, '10$^-20$'),
 (0.01, '10$^-2$'),
 (0.1, '10$^-1$'),
 (1, '10$^0$'),
 (10, '10$^1$'),
 (100, '10$^2$'),
 (1000, '10$^3$'),
 (100000000000000000000L, '10$^20$')]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
a = [0.01,0.1,10,100,1000]
for x in a:
     base,exp = "{0:.0e}".format(x).split('e')
     print "{0}0$^{1}$".format(base,exp)
```

**output:**

```
10$^-02$
10$^-01$
10$^+01$
10$^+02$
10$^+03$
```

Comment: This is `10$^+00$` for `1`, but since the OP didn't specify the behavior, that seems fine. May not work for non-10 inputs, but OP didn't specify that behavior either. Maybe there is a very small chance that rounding error will mess things up, perhaps with `{.0e}`? But I could not trigger it.

Comment: I personally would have written it `base,exp = "{0:.0e}".format(x).split('e')`, then `print "{0}0$^{1}$".format(base,exp)`

Comment: Also this is probably not what the OP wanted because it prepends 0s, and LaTeX would probably render it as 10<sup>-02</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Convert the number to scientific notation string:

```
s = string.format("%.3e",0.001)
```

then replace the e+ or e- with latex format:

```
s.replace("e+","$^{")
s.replace("e-","$^{")
```

then append the latex end brackets:

```
s = s + "}$"
```

that should output:

```
"1.000$^{-3}$"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for i in str(a):
    print i
```

Output:

```
0.01
0.1
10.0
100.0
1000.0
```

If you prefer scientific notation:

```
for i in str(a):
    print '%.3e' % i
```

Output:

```
1.000e-02
1.000e-01
1.000e+01
1.000e+02
1.000e+03
```

The digit in '%.3e' controls the number of digits to the right of the decimal point.

EDIT: if you want to print everything on the same line, add a comma ',' at the end of each print statement.

Comment: You could then replace 'e' with a '$^' by using string replacement.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but my question might have been not clear. I would like to have my string in scientific notation but in Latex format like 10$^{-2}$ and so on

Comment: @Matteo Sorry I meant using the str.replace() function after you format the string. So maybe something like s = str.format("%.3e",num) then s.replace("e+","$")

Comment: Ah, I didn't understand from your question that you wanted LaTeX output. I thought that was just your way of expressing that you wanted scientific notation. The other answers will get you sorted.